# Data Migration - What is the proper way to compare a SELECT COUNT statement when JUNIT Testing

Tags: java, data-migration

I keep getting assertion errors when I send this QUERY to the database even though when I manually enter in the query into both databases it returns the correct data. CAN YOUR TELL ME HOW I SHOULD BE COMPARING THESE TWO COUNTS??

The only difference is the column title, shown literally below(left is the MYSQL and right is MSSQL)

HERE IS THE QUERY AND RESULT

```
select count(userfieldid) from tr_userfield where calcexpression like '%@004%' and usefor like '%B%'

_____________________________________________
count(*)     |     (No Column Name)
_____________________________________________
43           |           43
             |
```

Here is my JAVA Code

```
package a7.unittests.dao;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import artemispm.autocalc.TRBaseScoreCalculator;

public class UnitTestTRBaseScoreCalculator_Select {
@Test
public void testQUERY_ISTHISCHARACINUSE() throws Exception{

    char WILDCARD = '%';

    UnitTestHelper helper = new UnitTestHelper();
    Connection con = helper.getConnection(helper.sourceDBUrl);
    Connection conTarget = helper.getConnection(helper.targetDBUrl);

    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(String.format(TRBaseScoreCalculator.QUERY_ISTHISCHARINUSE_1, WILDCARD, "@004", WILDCARD, WILDCARD, "B", WILDCARD));
    ResultSet sourceVal = stmt.executeQuery();
    stmt = conTarget.prepareStatement(String.format(TRBaseScoreCalculator.QUERY_ISTHISCHARINUSE_1, WILDCARD, "@004", WILDCARD, WILDCARD, "B", WILDCARD));
    ResultSet targetVal = stmt.executeQuery();
    assertTrue(helper.resultSetsEqual2(sourceVal,targetVal));   }

}

package a7.unittests.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class UnitTestHelper {




public Connection getConnection(String url)throws Exception{
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
}

/*
 * Use for Insert and Update and Delete Statements
 */

public boolean resultSetsEqual4 (int source, int target){

    System.out.println("The source is: "+source+" The target is: "+target);
    if(((source>0)&&(target>0)&&(target==source)))
    {

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

/*
 * Used to test SELECT statements passing in objects
 */


public boolean resultSetsEqual2 (ResultSet source, ResultSet target) throws SQLException{
    System.out.println("The source is: "+source+" The target is: "+target);
    while(source.next())
    {
        target.next();
        ResultSetMetaData metadata = source.getMetaData();
        int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
        for (int i =1; i<=count; i++)
        {
            if(!source.getObject(i).equals(target.getObject(i)))
            {return false;}
        }
    }
    return true;
}


public boolean resultSetsEqual (ResultSet source, ResultSet target) throws SQLException{

System.out.println("The source is: "+source+" The target is: "+target);
while(source.next())
{
    target.next();
    ResultSetMetaData metadata = source.getMetaData();
    int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
    for (int i =1; i<=count; i++)
    {
        if(source.getObject(i) != target.getObject(i))
        {return false;}
    }
}
return true;
}
public boolean resultSetsEqual3 (ResultSet rs1, ResultSet rs2) throws SQLException {
int col = 1;
//ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs1.getMetaData();
//int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
while (rs1.next() && rs2.next()) {
    final Object res1 = rs1.getObject(col);
    final Object res2 = rs2.getObject(col);
    // Check values
    if (!res1.equals(res2)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("%s and %s aren't equal at common position %d",
            res1, res2, col));
    }
    // rs1 and rs2 must reach last row in the same iteration
    if ((rs1.isLast() != rs2.isLast())) {
        throw new RuntimeException("The two ResultSets contains different number of columns!");
    }  
}
return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you debug what does target.getSource return? As for the column name, you can change the query to be:  select count(userfieldid) **as count_** from tr_userfield where calcexpression like '%@004%' and usefor like '%B%'

Comment: Right, I did.  I found that I needed to getInt() to compare the count in both d's return